# Computing E becomes chaotic at limits 10 ** 12 in Python?

Tags: python, floating-point

I wrote a program that computes the **base of natural logarithms** (known as **e** in mathematics) using the following well-known formula:

e = (1 + 1.0/n) ** n

The code is:

```
def e_formula(lim):
    n = lim
    e = (1 + 1.0/n) **n
    return e
```

I set up a test that iterates from 10**1 to 10**100:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(1,100):
        print e_formula(10**i)
```

However the following results around 10**11 blow up.

Actual results from shell:

2.5937424601

2.70481382942

2.71692393224

2.71814592682

2.71826823719

2.7182804691

2.71828169413

2.71828179835

2.71828205201

2.71828205323

**2.71828205336**

***2.71852349604***

2.71611003409

2.71611003409

3.03503520655

1.0

I am looking for a reason for this, either to do with the result exceeding the floating-point limit in a 32-bit machine or because of the way Python itself computes floating point numbers. I am not looking for a better solution; I just want to understand why it blows up.

Answer (score 5):

This is simply due to the limited precision of floating point numbers. You get about 15 significant digits.

You are taking `(1 + very_small_number)`. Most of the digits of `very_small_number` are truncated at this stage.

The `**n` just multiplies this error

Comment: I thought this would be the answer, do you know if it is the mantissa or exponent that truncates first? I would guess mantissa as it is an accuracy problem?

Comment: Do you have a link to these standards would be very useful: also what is difference IEE and 11RC. I know the theory but do not have practical experience:)

Comment: @pythonMan IIRC == If I Recall Correctly :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: sorry:) I get it now! Just wondering how you know that it is 15 digits or if you did a quick back of the envelope decimal to binary conversion. I know IEE has a weired way ( to me anyway) of adding 127 to mantissa and exponenet during conversion. It would be nice to work through the example when we did theory :}

Comment: @pythonMan, 2**52 has 16 decimal digits, so you can only guarantee 15

Comment: nailed it , great I can use it as a good example now then get the old debugger out thanks

Comment: Does Python have double precision and would it give different answer if I ran the same program?

Comment: @pythonMan, Python floats _are_ doubles. There are no single precision floats in Python